# Insert &#039; into a JS object

Tags: jquery

I'm using jquery to insert a string into an object with .html().

The problem is that if I insert the escaped ' which is `&#039;` it automatically decodes it.

I've tried .text() with the same result.

How can I add a string to an element in an object, when that string contains `&#039;` and not have it automatically decoded?

For example, I want to insert this string into the second td:

```
&#039; &quot; &lt; &gt;
```

Using .html() I get:

```
<tbody><tr><td></td></tr><tr><td>' " &lt; &gt;</td></tr></tbody>
```

Thanks

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/zct5G/ ??

Comment: Indent code or backtick it--I indented it but don't know if what you wrote was what you meant.

Comment: What's your code look like, and what sort of file is that code in?

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  Was editing myself when you did the job.

Comment: Its just running through a number of js / jquery functions - in a .js file

Answer (score 1):

Escape the ampersand:

```
&amp;#039;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately i can't do that because the function is meant to build an object that i then turn back into a string to send to my server.  I could just build the whole thing through a string, but the function is used to parse a table to edit, load and save, making it multifunctional and difficult to change for the use of only one of those reasons.  Escaping the ampersand unfortunately creates problems down the line.